# Sending a file with Java Sockets, losing data

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I'm trying to send a file from a client to a server with Sockets in Java.  It works fine when I am testing on the same machine, but when I test across different machines, I lose large chunks of data, resulting in a corrupted file.  If I try to send a very small file (<20 bytes), it doesn't even reach the println inside the server's while loop.

Here is my code:

**Server.java**

```
package edu.mst.cs.sensorreceiver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private static final int PORT = 51111;
    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
    private static final File _downloadDir = new File("downloads/");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!_downloadDir.exists()) {
            if (!_downloadDir.mkdirs()) {
                System.err.println("Error: Could not create download directory");
            }
        }

        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
                socket = server.accept();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                String name = in.readLine();
                File file = new File(_downloadDir, name);

                String size = in.readLine();
                int fileSize;
                try {
                    fileSize = Integer.parseInt(size);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.err.println("Error: Malformed file size:" + size);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

                System.out.println("Saving " + file + " from user... (" + fileSize + " bytes)");
                saveFile(file, socket.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("Finished downloading " + file + " from user.");
                if (file.length() != fileSize) {
                    System.err.println("Error: file incomplete");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void saveFile(File file, InputStream inStream) {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
            int bytesRead;
            int pos = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE)) >= 0) {
                pos += bytesRead;
                System.out.println(pos + " bytes (" + bytesRead + " bytes read)");
                fileOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileOut != null) {
                try {
                    fileOut.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Finished, filesize = " + file.length());
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
package edu.mst.cs.sensorreceiver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    private static final String HOSTNAME = "131.151.163.153";
    private static final int PORT = 51111;
    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sendFile(args[0]);
    }

    private static void sendFile(String path) {
        if (path == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Path is null");
        }

        File file = new File(path);
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
            socket = new Socket(HOSTNAME, PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to server at " + socket.getInetAddress());

            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            out.println(file.getName());
            out.println(file.length());

            System.out.println("Sending " + file.getName() + " (" + file.length() + " bytes) to server...");
            writeFile(file, socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Finished sending " + file.getName() + " to server");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeFile(File file, OutputStream outStream) {
        FileInputStream reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
            int pos = 0;
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE)) >= 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                outStream.flush();
                pos += bytesRead;
                System.out.println(pos + " bytes (" + bytesRead + " bytes read)");
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println("Error while reading file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error while writing " + file.toString() + " to output stream");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been working on this for hours and I have made almost no progress.  I thought I had a pretty good understanding of how reading/writing from streams works, but clearly I'm missing something here.

Again, everything works perfectly when I am sending and receiving from the same machine.  But if I try to send a file between two computers, even if the two are on the same LAN, I lose a lot of the data that was sent.

Can anybody figure out my problem?  I've already tried everything I could think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be mixing chunked data and line oriented operation. I suggest you use a [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) on the server, and a [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html). Starting on the client, something like

```
private static void sendFile(String path) {
    if (path == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Path is null");
    }

    File file = new File(path);
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
        socket = new Socket(HOSTNAME, PORT);
        System.out.println("Connected to server at "
                + socket.getInetAddress());

        try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));) {
            dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
            dos.writeLong(file.length());

            System.out.println("Sending " + file.getName() + " ("
                    + file.length() + " bytes) to server...");
            writeFile(file, dos);
            System.out.println("Finished sending " + file.getName()
                    + " to server");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the server

```
socket = server.accept();

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String name = dis.readUTF();
File file = new File(_downloadDir, name);
long fileSize = dis.readLong();
System.out.println("Saving " + file + " from user... ("
        + fileSize + " bytes)");
```

Comment: Wow, you're right, that fixed it.  I didn't realize that mixing the different types of streams could be so problematic, although it makes sense now that I think about it.  Thanks, I won't make that mistake again.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you mixes all that should never be mixed: (a) input/output streams, (b) PrintStream, (c) stream reader and (d) buffered reader. this hell leads to described behavior.

you should use the only object (stream) to write all your staff. and the only object (stream) to read all your staff.

I can recommend you to use either

```
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); // for writing
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // for reading
```

or

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

The first is more flexible, the second is simpler to use.